# What is Lionel Fusco's actual rank in Person of Interest?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, person-of-interest

In the pilot, the corrupt prosecutor Diane Hansen refers to Lionel Fusco as *Officer* following his testimony at her trial. He's later referred to as a Detective throughout most of the series. However, in a few episodes following his apprehension of Patrick Simmons he's referred to as a Lieutenant (presumably due to the notability he gained from making such a high-profile arrest), but then he goes back to being referred to as a Detective throughout the rest of the series.

What's his actual rank, and why did they keep changing their mind about what it actually was?

Comment: *"However, in a few episodes he's referred to as a Lieutenant..."* Which ones? Can you be specific?

Comment: @CinCout It's the episodes after he brings in Patrick Simmons.

Comment: Season and episode number will help me narrow it down. I watched the series long back.